# How to read a zip file off of Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

We are currently getting events published to Cloud PubSub about SFTP arrivals from Google Cloud Storage, and we can process those easy enough in real time, but we are having an issue when we are trying to read the ZIP files off of Google Cloud Storage. The Python side of apache beam makes it pretty seamless with this class from the API, e.g.:

```
import apache_beam as beam

gcs = beam.io.gcsio.GcsIO()
```

And this seams to be able to pull off the files from Google Cloud Storage with relative ease, what I was wondering is if there was an equivalent to this python version in the Java version. A lot of Documentation points to using the [com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.6.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-storage/1.6.0/) from MCR, which we have done before, it just felt much more clunky compared to the python version and wanted to get some clarification on just how to do this correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific issue are you having when reading ZIP files from GCS with Beam Java? TextIO automatically decompresses ZIP files; if you need something more custom, use the methods in the FileSystems class (in fact this is the recommended API in Python too, instead of GcsIO).

Comment: We are shipping data up to the cloud, and PubSub is telling our pipelines where the data is to go process it. The data in the ZIP files is not textual(well 2 are technically) but the rest are images and pdf's. The TextIO.read() methods appear to only be able to return PCollection<String>

Answer (score 0):

The [FileSystems API](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.java) supports your use case. See the implementation of [FileIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java) for some examples of its usage; you may want to borrow some more patterns from it.